# Como obter a lista de usuários do site pela API do Stack Overflow?

Tags: python, api, stackexchange

Preciso fazer um loop na API do Stack Overflow para gerar dados de todos os usuários do fórum, mas não sei como os id's dos usuários são gerados na hora do cadastro. Alguém sabe como os IDs dos usuários são gerados? Não são de forma crescente, creio eu.

Comment: Não sei se podes fazer isso, se o SOpt permite.

Comment: Fazer o loop, tem como. Eu só não sei como o ID de cada usuário é criado, porque não parece que é de forma crescente, analisando a quantidade de usuário com o tamanho dos ID's.

Comment: Os IDs creio que são seqüenciais, mas tem os usuários excluídos que não são listados. Mas por que você precisa saber como são gerados?

Comment: Para pegar a lista de usuários do site: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users (não sei como a biblioteca python lida com isso).

Comment: Porque como eu havia dito, eu preciso pegar informações de todos os usuários, mas se você pegar no site do stack, da para saber quantos usuários existem, mas existe ID muito maior do que o numero máximo de usuários, pensei que fosse os excluídos, mas o número é bem maior por isso queria saber como o ID de cada usuário é escolhido para tentar gerar todos os ID's e depois colocá-los em um loop buscando os dados de cada usuário.

Comment: Tem gente que usa como **nome** o ID no SO em Inglês, onde o número é gigante. Essa idéia de *"saber como o ID de cada usuário é escolhido"* é furada e recomendo esquecer isso. Use a API pra puxar todos e pronto.

Comment: Usando a API a pesquisa de puxar todos de uma vez, não me responde literalmente todos os usuários do fórum. Pelo menos eu não consegui retorno de todos os usuários aqui "http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users".

Comment: @Pythowner O resultado é paginado; você precisa solicitar as outras páginas via parâmetro 'page' (por exemplo, http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?page=2&site=stackoverflow )

Comment: Sim, entendi isso, mas como sei a quantidade máxima de paginas?

Answer (score 2):

Para obter a **lista de usuários** de um dos sites Stack Exchange:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?site=[SiteDesejado]
```

Exemplo: http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?site=stackoverflow

Para obter o **total de usuários** de um dos sites:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=[SiteDesejado]
```

Exemplo: http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=stackoverflow

Elemento relevante:

```
{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "total_users":3321752
      }
   ],
}
```

Comment: Amigão, sim. Porém não vem literalmente todos os usuários como resposta.

Comment: @Pythowner Se reparar no final da resposta Json, há o seguinte trecho: `"has_more":true,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":298`. Isso significa que (1) a API diz que existem mais usuários, portanto ela funciona como uma espécia de paginação, e (2) existe uma quota de pesquisa (diária) de pesquisas, então talvez seja necessário continuar em outro dia a listagem dos usuários. Veja [esta resposta](http://stackapps.com/a/3233) para mais detalhes e ver **como listar outras páginas da lista de usuários**.

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu descubro o quantidade total de páginas?